# How to find the max/min element of linked list

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, max, min

I have a doubly linked list in my case. And I want to find the max and min element. So I want to use the Collections to find it. Here is my code below for Node first:

```
public class Node<T> {
    Node<T> prev;
    Node<T> next;
    T data;

    public Node(T _data)
    {
        data = _data;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(T _data, Node<T> _prev, Node<T> _next)
    {
        data = _data;
        prev = _prev;
        next = _next;
    }

    T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> _next)
    {
        next = _next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node<T> _prev)
    {
        prev = _prev;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public Node<T> getPrev()
    {
        return prev;
    }
}
```

And here is my Doubly Linked List class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    int listCount = 0;

    public void traverseF()
    {
        Node<T> temp = head;

        while(temp != null)
        {
            System.out.print(temp.getData() + " ");
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }

    public void traverseB()
    {
        Node<T> temp = tail;

        while(temp != null)
        {
            System.out.print(temp.getData() + " ");
            temp = temp.getPrev();
        }
    }

    public void insertFirst(T data)
    {
        Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(data);
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp.setNext(null);
            temp.setPrev(null);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.setNext(head);
            head.setPrev(temp);
            head = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

So, my main code is:

```
import java.util.Collections;


public class glavna {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> DLL = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();

        DLL.insertFirst(32);
        DLL.insertFirst(22);
        DLL.insertFirst(55);
        DLL.insertFirst(10);

        DLL.traverseF();

        Integer max = Collections.max(DLL);

    }
}
```

How exactly do I call the Collections.max or Collections.min method? Isn't the list only necessary to find the max/min elements?

```
public T getMin()
{
    Node<T> temp = head;
    T min = head.getData();
    while(temp.getNext() != null)
    {
        if(temp.getData() < min) // error
        {
            //min = temp.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DoublyLinkedList` should implement `Collection` interface, i.e. `public class DoublyLinkedList implements Collection`. Then you will be able to call `Collections.max(DLL)`

Comment: Another alternative to implement the Collection interface, is to keep track of current min and max in your `insertFirst()` method. Then just create a `getMin()` and `getMax()` methods to return the mininum and maximum values in O(1).

Comment: @kiruwka What exactly is 'Collection' interface? Is there any example how can I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: @user12831231 see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). You need to implement iterator() mainly, the rest could be stubs. IMHO, this is an overkill for simply finding min/max. Why can't you just create simple getMin/Max methods, for instance based on Jose Rui Santos suggestion ?

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I believe it makes more sense to implement getMin/Max methods in conventional O(N) way, assuming one day he needs `remove()` method for his list

Comment: @kiruwka Check my main post, and see if it's possible to do something like that? I have an error which says I can't use the < method, it's undefined. How can I continue?

Comment: @kiruwka In that case, if the item to be removed `n` in `remove(n)` equals the current min or max, then we just need to find the new min or max in O(n). This way we can still have getters in constanst time O(1), since they are usually more often invoked. Obviously, this is not needed if list is also keep sorted. In this case, min is first elem, max the last one.

Comment: Well, considering the Collections method would take a lot of things to implement, add and learn, I'll go for the simpler way and make a separate function. However, since I'm using generics, I can't use the <. How can I compare the elements with generic data? I am using only Integers in the program, but I guess I have to implement the function with generic type, if I decide to use something else later.

Comment: @user12831231 To compare generics, your `T` must implement the `Comparable` interface. Then compare using the `compareTo` method.

Comment: @user12831231 or you can use `Comparator` instead. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement `getMin` with generics you need to be able to compare them. You can, for instance, provide a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to your method:

```
public T getMin(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    Node<T> temp = head.getNext();
    T min = head.getData();
    while(temp != null) {
        T candidateValue = temp.getData();
        if (comparator.compare(candidateValue, min) < 0) { // equivalent to candidate < min
            min = candidateValue;
        }
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return min;
}
```

Then, calling your method for `Integer` :

```
getMin(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
    }
 });
```

Another approach is to make your list only keep [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) items :

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
```

and then have your `getMin()` method use `compareTo` method :

```
public T getMin() {
    Node<T> temp = head.getNext();
    T min = head.getData();
    while(temp != null) {
        T candidateValue = temp.getData();
        if (candidateValue.compareTo(min) < 0) { // equivalent to candidate < min
            min = candidateValue;
        }
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return min;
}
```

Second approach is less verbose, as `Integer` is `Comparable` (i.e. implements Comparable for you already), so you won't need to change any other code.

Comment: In this line: `if (comparator.compareTo(min) < 0)` what exactly is comparator? Where is it defined?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry, i edited it. It is the candidateValue comparison with min

Answer (score 1):

You list is not a Collection, so you cannot use Collections with it.

Comment: Is there any short example, how can I make my list a Collection?

Comment: @user12831231 It must implement Collection interface to be a Collection.

Comment: So, I have to do `interface Collection{}` and then add `implements Collection` in the class, or do I have to declare the methods inside the collection too?

Comment: @user12831231 you need to implement the existing Collections interface. It sounds like you're not familiar with interfaces, so I'd recommend reading up on them. In short, they define a "contract", but you'll definitely need to understand them a little deeper before you'll be able to finish this. Here's the first tutorial I've found. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm (I honestly haven't read it). Once you've read that and you've implemented the Collection interface, you'll be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) method expects an argument which implements [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). The easiest way would probably be to extend `AbstractCollection` and add these methods:

```
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private Node<T> node = head;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T next = node.data;
            node = node.getNext();
            return next;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int size() {
    int size = 0;
    Node<T> node = head;
    while (node != null) {
        size++;
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks a lot. I think it's out of my level of understanding though. I'll do my best to study it.